# NoClassDefFound error - Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, noclassdeffounderror

Right now, I'm compiling my .class files in eclipse and moving them over to my `%tomcat_home%\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes` directory. They compile just fine.

I also have in the `...\classes` directory a `org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar` which I have verified has the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` class inside it.

However, I get a `NoClassDefFound` error when I run my class and it tries to `DriverManagerDataSource source = new DriverManagerDataSource();`

I don't understand why it wouldn't be finding that jar.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jar files in webapp should be placed in `WEB-INF/lib`, not in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that... thanks! Now on to the next roadblock...